# Finding number of lines passing through common segment of lines from overlapping multiple line shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, origin-destination

I have 16 different origin-destination route’s shapefile. 16 line shapefiles are different. I want to overlay these lines and find the common segments of these overlays routes. Suppose, one line is A-B, another is P-Q, another one is X-Y; I want to know how many routes go through C-D segment, how many go through E-F segment. I mean I want to separate the number of the routes by link.

How can I do this?

I imported the shapefiles from google map and shapefile have no feature class.

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would try using the [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool on your 16 shapefiles because it:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

However, to fully analyse the number of linear features that overlay you will probably need to use the [Overlay Route Events](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/location-referencing-roads-toolbox/overlay-route-events.htm) tool (from Linear Referencing) which:

> Overlays two or more linear event feature layers against a target
>   network and outputs a feature class or event table that represents the
>   dynamic segmentation of the inputs.

Comment: I tried. I when I try for 16 all, it shows warning 000953 and warning 000117. I am actually new to GIS, so I don't know much about this. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that this may shows as there is no single common section for all 16 routes. I should specify my question again. From these 16 routes, I need those segment of the routes which have used as minimum more than one route. I also need to know, those common section used as common section for how many routes. Thanks.